# Is it possible to setCurrentItem(pos) of PagerAdapter but don't scroll if that item is already visible?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a PagerAdapter which displays 2 items at a time.
Let's say there are 3 items in total. First and second is displayed. When I do setCurrentItem(1) the pager then gets updated and shows second and third item. Is it possible to make it still show first and second?

A workaround like setCurrentItem(pos-1) will not work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to make it still show first and second?

No, sorry.

However, you could use `getCurrentItem()` and compare it against your desired value, and skip calling `setCurrentItem()` altogether if it is not needed, using something like:

```
if (pager.getCurrentItem()!=pageYouWant && pager.getCurrentItem()+1!=pageYouWant) {
  pager.setCurrentItem(pageYouWant);
}
```